# How to get to invoice link in invoices api

Tags: freshbooks-api

I am interested to have a invoice link/pdf from the api which returns the invoice using new freshbooks api endpoint https://api.freshbooks.com/accounting/account/<accountid>/invoices/<invoiceid>

Even including `direct_links` I am unable to get the link to the invoice. With `direct_links` it returns json with fields `id`, `contactid`, `created_date`, `type`, `userid`, `objectid`, `token`.

Answer (score 1):

I currently work at FreshBooks.

Unfortunately these direct link tokens will only work with old FreshBooks, which isn't mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.freshbooks.com/api/invoices) -- I'll see if we can fix that.

Poking through, it doesn't look like we've has exposed a way to access a PDF version of the invoice through the public API just yet. But I'll pass that on to the appropriate channels and I'll update this answer if that changes.

Comment: Do you know if this ended up being implemented? I want to pipe a PDF through our server, and I see an example for downloading an invoice as PDF in the PostMan collection, but nothing in the docs, and I'm getting 400 Bad Requests trying to follow the example in the collection.

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg it might be worth sending in a support ticket for this! I no longer work at FreshBooks